# How to know what plugins were installed in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am working in a WordPress project that for some reason the plugins disappeared, the data still exits but neither the project owner or me know what plugins were installed. For example I knew `contact form 7` was installed because it showed me `[contact-form-7 id="424"]` in the page, I installed it and I can see the plugin now

there are other plugins for user authentication, permissions, etc. But how could I know which were installed?

there are no plugins in the plugins page so I need to check in the db or anywhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I would try and determine why all the plugins aren't showing up (perhaps the `/wp-content/plugins/` folder got renamed? It's a common way to quickly disable all plugins for diagnostics)

Beyond that, if you go to your `wp_options` table, there is a an option called `active_plugins` that contains a [serialized array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) of the active plugin files that looks like:

```
a:13:{i:0;s:29:"gravityforms/gravityforms.php";i:1;s:19:"akismet/akismet.php"; … }
```

It sounds like your database is fine, consider page content is unaffected, so this should suffice in getting you a list of active plugins, provided they haven't been registered as inactive due to the plugin files not being found - if so you'll probably want to dig through a database backup from when it was working (and if you have a "Full Backup" you may even be able to restore the plugin files from there)

*Note: Serialized arrays can be a pain to read, you can either dump the unserialized value in your own script, or use an online tool like [this](https://www.unserialize.com/) or [this](https://www.functions-online.com/unserialize.html) to get a more readable format.*